# PHP ↔ Perl interface or bindings

Tags: php, perl, interface, binding

What PHP ↔ Perl interface or bindings do you recommend?

I need to be able to run Perl functions located in a Perl file from a PHP script and get the return values.

I've already found the [PECL "perl" package](http://pecl.php.net/package/perl) but I'm not sure how reliable it is since the last Subversion activity was ~12 months ago.

I've also found the Perl module [PHP::Interpreter](http://p3rl.org/PHP%3a%3aInterpreter) that is supposed to work both ways according to an almost 3 year old tutorial, *[Integrating PHP and Perl](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9282)*.

I would really appreciate it if you can recommend (or not) either of those 2 options or if you've got a better option that I haven't seen yet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030736/how-can-i-use-perl-libraries-from-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635612/how-to-include-pl-perl-file-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276654/perl-interpreter-for-php

Comment: Not sure which answer to choose as the "right" one. Both link to similar tools (I knew of and have used Thrift before). What to do? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never used any of those, but they look interesting..

Take a look at [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) as well.. more overhead in systems like these but you get other cool stuff :) Guess it depends on your needs ..

Comment: I'm going to check this one out. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: Selecting this one as the correct answer since I didn't know about Gearman but I've already used Thrift before.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would probably be [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/). It connects those languages (and a lot more) between each other. The only downside is requiring a network server to run and receive those requests on either side.

Comment: I've used Thrift before and I was hoping for something with less overhead. I'm going to keep Thrift in mind though. Thanks a lot for your answer!